Why is docker compose say unsupported config option when starting database container on one machine but not on the other?
I've been working on a project as a test. I used Docker so that the containers could be migrated to a different machine and the project could be started locally.
However, when the engineer enters this comand to start the database container the terminal throws an error
docker-compose up -d db

ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services: 'db'
The problem is that I cannot recreate the error myself, the container starts when I enter the command. I also tested it on a different pc and there are no errors there either.
this is my docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./:/app

  php:
    build: ./
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=chargebox"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "chargebox"
      POSTGRES_USER: "symfony"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "123"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: db

I have searched the web but all I can find is that it might be a problem with the indentation, however after installing the indent-rainbow extension for Vs-Code it looks to me like everything is in order.
I have also asked to check which docker compose version is installed. My version is 2.27.0-desktop.2 the version they are running is 2.27.1-desktop.1
Could the problem be there? I don't know where else to search since they are reviewing this project remotely and I am not able to recreate the issue.
Sidenote: I do know that putting sensitive info in the docker compose file is not safe, but this is a test project with no actual sensitive information. Since this is my first time using docker I am still figuring out how to use secrets.

Do you get the same error if you create a new directory, place only the compose file listed above, and run the same docker-compose command?

I tried that, not getting error. Also my docker-compose version is v2.27.1-desktop.1 on WSL.

There are two different interpretations of a Compose file without a version: line.  If you have the old Python version of Compose installed, and you're invoking it as docker-compose, then this is a "version 1" Compose file: it doesn't have a top-level services: block, and it doesn't support Docker networks or named volumes.  If you're using the newer Go version of Compose, then it ignores the version: line and treats every file as though it uses the current version of "specification" file format.
It sounds like the system you're installing on has both versions of Compose installed, and you're getting the older version when you run docker-compose up (with a hyphen).  That's interpreting it as the "version 1" file format, with a single service named services:.  You can do two things to address this:

Add a version: line to the top of the Compose file.  I'd recommend version: '2.4' or version: '3.8'; either will work.  The newer Compose will give you an (IMHO incorrect) warning that the line is obsolete, but you can ignore it.

Make sure you run docker compose with a space and not docker-compose with a hyphen.



Thank you! I suggested this as solution but it didn't work either. They got it working on a different machine eventually so I still don't know what the issue was exactly.
